# Oracle loader with Skip Option

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Here i tell the loader to skip the 2 first lines of the file.csv
but it doesnt skip the lines. it still tell me that he cant skip the 2 lines.

**translated error message:**

***line 1: skiped - all columns are null***

***line 2: refused - Error in table test_table, column id.***

***ORA-01722: invalid number.***

Here the loader try to load the line 2 into the test_table but failed because of the column "COMP" from the line 2.

So can someone tell what i m doing wrong here. Thx for help

### control_file.ctl

```
OPTIONS (SKIP = 2)
Load truncate
into table test_table
fields terminated by ';' 
trailing nullcols
(
  field1 filler,
  system filler,
  id,
  Firstname,
  Lastname,
  field5 filler,
  field6 filler,
  status,
  newid
 )
```

---Table to be loaded---------------

```
 CREATE TABLE test_table(
       id NUMBER(30),  
   Firstname VARCHAR2(50),
   Lastname VARCHAR2(50),
   status NUMBER(1),
   newid VARCHAR2(50)
  );
```

------file.csv------------------------

```
"1";"1";"BG3784";"1233";"2018-09-29+02:00";"07:51:12.427+02:00"
"2";"COMP";;"";
"3";"TESTSERVER";1;"John";"Donald";;;1;"22117"
"3";"TESTSERVER";2;"Toto";"Smith";;;0;"22969"
"3";"TESTSERVER";3;"Leonardo";"Pitt";;;;"81247"
"3";"TESTSERVER";4;"Micheal";"Bron";;;;"51149"
```

Comment: `OPTIONS (SKIP = 2)` looks perfectly fine and it should work.

Comment: I've used your control file, table defintion and CSV file and verified it does exactly what you expected, in 11.2.0.4. No errors, the log says "Number to skip: 2", and four rows inserted correctly. Your 'line 1 skipped' message doesn't make sense for the CSV you showed either though, so somewhere you aren't running quite what you think?

Comment: Add `optionally enclosed by '"'` after `fields terminated by ';'` and try changing the name of `id` to `cust_id`. ID being a reserved word can cause issues.  Just stay away from naming objects the same as reserved words.

Comment: i named it "id" for the test.

Comment: thanks you all for urs comments.@Alex Poole i will try again i really dont know why it doesnt work for me.

Comment: thank you again. The issue is now resolved. In my file all columns are enclosed by ' " '. So as @Gary_W  said the optionally enclosed by ' " ' was missing. To my understanding the loader try to load "1234" as a string into the number field id  and failed because i didnt put the optionally enclosed by ' " ' in the control file.